# Webdriverio how to do a TAB key action

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, dom-events, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO with latest Chrome browser v77 and chromedriver v77.

When I try to do a `browser.keys("\uE004")`, I got an error:

> Error:
>      The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.
>           at actions([object Object]) - keys.js:94:2.

Also I tried `browser.keys("Tab")`. That also didn't work. So anyone please help like I need to do a <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key action. How I can perform that. Currently this small issue is a huge blocker for all our automation. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.setValue('input', ['Tab'])
```

multiple key press can be done using

```
browser.setValue('input', ['CTRL', 'A'])
```

Comment: Explain a little bit of information with code, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector.setValue("Tab");

Answer (score -1):

```
await browser.keys("\ue004") //Tab
```

Comment: please write some details and explain what have you done